# How do I get the result of a function to print onto an HTML document but also editable?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, matrix

I've been trying to create a basic matrix inverse calculator which I think I've done now on the back end side of it but I can't figure out how to get the HTML document to interact with the js code like I want it to and I can't figure out how to find what I want online.

1. I want the Original Matrix (M) to be visible in the HTML textarea.
2. I want the Inverse of the matrix in the text area to display underneath the textarea once button has been pressed.
3. I want to be able to edit the original matrix in the text area so that when I click the calculate button it will update the inverse matrix accordingly.

Any help and pointers I appreciate.

This is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    
</head>
<body>

  <h1>Inverse of 3x3 Matrix Calculator</h1>

  <p><textarea id='input-matrix'>Enter Your 3x3 Matrix</textarea></p>

  <button>Calculate</button>
  
  <script>
var M = [[3,8,6],
         [4,3,6],
         [7,8,9]];

function invert_matrix(M) { 

if(M[0].length !== M.length) { 
    return;
}
}


var D = M[0][0] * (M[1][1] * M[2][2] - M[1][2] * M[2][1]) - M[0][1] * (M[1][0] * M[2][2] - M[1][2] * M[2][0]) + M[0][2] * (M[1][0] * M[2][1] - M[1][1] * M[2][0]); 

var det = 1 / D; 

var I = []; 

for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++) { 
    I[I.length] = []
}

I[0][0] = [M[1][1] * M[2][2] - M[2][1] * M[1][2]] * det; 
I[0][1] = [M[0][2] * M[2][1] - M[0][1] * M[2][2]] * det; 
I[0][2] = [M[0][1] * M[1][2] - M[0][2] * M[1][1]] * det;
I[1][0] = [M[1][2] * M[2][0] - M[1][0] * M[2][2]] * det;
I[1][1] = [M[0][0] * M[2][2] - M[0][2] * M[2][0]] * det;
I[1][2] = [M[1][0] * M[0][2] - M[0][0] * M[1][2]] * det;
I[2][0] = [M[1][0] * M[2][1] - M[2][0] * M[1][1]] * det;
I[2][1] = [M[2][0] * M[0][1] - M[0][0] * M[2][1]] * det;
I[2][2] = [M[0][0] * M[1][1] - M[1][0] * M[0][1]] * det;

</script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Interaction with the HTML DOM

Your first issue is that it appears that you've not attempted to call upon the variables and functions that allow you to interact with your HTML page. There's plentiful resources online on how to do this, and a hundred dozen opinionated frameworks that complicate doing this, but we can start simple, and put you on the right path.

You can store references to the elements on the DOM in variables in JS. The easiest way to grab an element is to pull it by its ID. Thankfully, you've already given your input field an id of `input-matrix`, so we can do this:

```js
var my_input = document.getElementById("input-matrix");
```

If you were to do this in your web console aka the developer tools, you'd be able to see that my_input has quite a few properties, including `value`. For input elements, this is where the string content of the input is stored. You can also force it to display what you'd like instead.

```js
my_input.value = "Hello!";
```

But of course, that's not what you want.

## Displaying your Matrix

So, you have a matrix.

```js
var M = [[3,8,6],
         [4,3,6],
         [7,8,9]];
```

We'll certainly use it. But we need to be able to swap between the string format and this array format. Your input wouldn't understand this at all.

Thankfully, there's an easy way. We already know that rows are separated by newlines (the `\n` character) and numbers will be separated by either commas or spaces (I'll use single spaces).

So what we'll do is make two functions to help us: `matrix_to_str` and `str_to_matrix`. We'll start with the former to achieve your ask #1.

```js
function matrix_to_str(matrix) {
    return matrix.map(row => row.join(" ") ).join("\n");
}
```

We take in *any* matrix. Since a matrix is an array (of arrays), we can *map* over each item in the array. In this case, each 'item' is one of your rows, aka another array. `map` is a function that is applied to every item, and the result of that function takes the item's place. For example: `[1,2,3].map(x=>x+1)` results in `[2,3,4]`.

In our case, we take every row, and we're transforming it. First, we `join` all the items in the `row` array, transforming it into a string separated by our chosen delimiter, which in this case is a space `" "`. This makes the `map` result for each row a nice string. Then, we take that array of nice strings and join again, this time separated by newlines.

So now:

```js
var M = [[3,8,6],
        [4,3,6],
        [7,8,9]];

function matrix_to_str(matrix) {
    return matrix.map(row => row.join(" ") ).join("\n");
}

var my_input = document.getElementById("input-matrix");
my_input.value = matrix_to_str(M);
```

Loading the page will now show the matrix in the input box as you desired, separated by spaces for each item and newlines for each row.

## Displaying Elsewhere & Button..

Since you want a 'result' area for displaying the inverted matrix, let's go ahead and add that. The easiest way is to simply create another element with a new id that we'll edit the contents of each time we have a new matrix result. There are other approaches, such as creating a new element through JS with `document.createElement`, but we'll put that aside in favor of the more practical approach. So after your Calculate button, I'm adding this:

```html
<div id="result-matrix"></div>
```

Now, we need some way of making the display. For now, we'll ignore the need for an inverted matrix and simply test the button displaying our same matrix from the input. Herein lies another problem you have: your button isn't set to do anything. You'll typically want to direct it to a function. We'll make a function, called `display_results`, so on our button, we'll edit the HTML:

```
<button onclick="display_results()">Calculate</button>
```

This won't be the final function for Calculate, but serves the purpose for this section. Now:

```js
function display_results() {
    document.getElementById("result-matrix").innerText = matrix_to_str(M);
}
```

I'm selecting the `result-matrix` and setting its `innerText` to the result of our matrix. There's a similar property called `textContent`, but while textContent tends to be cleaner, it isn't a fan of reading out formatting for newlines. `innerText`, however, transforms newlines into `<br>` (linebreak) tags, which suits our needs here. There are again other approaches you could take, but that would require changing our `matrix_to_str` function or making a new one entirely.

But now we have interactivity! Clicking the button displays the matrix M. But you wanted it to be dependent on the value of the input. We can do that, too:

```js
function display_results() {
    document.getElementById("result-matrix").innerText = my_input.value;
}
```

This of course assumes that `my_input` is still in scope.

And it also doesn't help you with your final goal just yet.

## String Representation to Matrix

We circle back around to the aforementioned `str_to_matrix`. And here we build it:

```js
function str_to_matrix(str) {
    return str.split("\n").map(row_str => row_str.split(" ").map(item => Number(item)));
}
```

This time, I'm pulling apart the string by the delimiter using `split`, which transforms a string into an array with the items separated by the specified delimiter. I pull the string apart by newline first, then `map` over each of those strings to separate them further, by space this time. Finally, for each of *those* new strings, I transform them into numbers.

## Your code in function

I'll leave your inversion code *almost* entirely alone. The trouble you have is that you've not made your inversion code a function. But since you'll be dynamically pulling content from the web element, not a predefined variable `M`, we'll want to functionize your inversion code. And it looks like you had already started, so we'll continue your `invert_matrix` function.

```js
function invert_matrix(M) { 

    if(M[0].length !== M.length) { 
        return;
    }

    var D = M[0][0] * (M[1][1] * M[2][2] - M[1][2] * M[2][1]) - M[0][1] * (M[1][0] * M[2][2] - M[1][2] * M[2][0]) + M[0][2] * (M[1][0] * M[2][1] - M[1][1] * M[2][0]); 

    var det = 1 / D; 

    var I = []; 

    for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++) { 
        I[I.length] = []
    }

    I[0][0] = [M[1][1] * M[2][2] - M[2][1] * M[1][2]] * det; 
    I[0][1] = [M[0][2] * M[2][1] - M[0][1] * M[2][2]] * det; 
    I[0][2] = [M[0][1] * M[1][2] - M[0][2] * M[1][1]] * det;
    I[1][0] = [M[1][2] * M[2][0] - M[1][0] * M[2][2]] * det;
    I[1][1] = [M[0][0] * M[2][2] - M[0][2] * M[2][0]] * det;
    I[1][2] = [M[1][0] * M[0][2] - M[0][0] * M[1][2]] * det;
    I[2][0] = [M[1][0] * M[2][1] - M[2][0] * M[1][1]] * det;
    I[2][1] = [M[2][0] * M[0][1] - M[0][0] * M[2][1]] * det;
    I[2][2] = [M[0][0] * M[1][1] - M[1][0] * M[0][1]] * det;

    return I;

}
```

As promised, I've left it alone, aside from adding a `return I`. Now, I can pass it any matrix and expect it to be inverted. **This is critical:** *always aim to build your code, as much as you can, into sensible functions that perform one task exceptionally well.*

## Altogether

`display_results` needs a revamp:

```js
function display_results(matrix) {
    document.getElementById("result-matrix").innerText = matrix_to_str(matrix);
}
```

And it'll no longer be our button's call. Instead, it's doing one thing well: taking a matrix and displaying it on our screen.

The button will now invoke our only new function: `run_invert`.

```html
<button onclick="run_invert()">Calculate</button>
```

This will piece all our various functions together. Note that now, it's the sole function in our program that has no parameters:

```js
function run_invert(){
    var current_matrix = str_to_matrix(document.getElementById("input-matrix").value);
    var inverted = invert_matrix(current_matrix);
    display_results(inverted);
}
```

We take the current value of the input, pass it to `str_to_matrix` to build a matrix out of it, then hand that matrix to the inverter. The result of this is another matrix, which `display_results` eagerly accepts as its sole parameter.

Here's all of my code after it all:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    
</head>
<body>

  <h1>Inverse of 3x3 Matrix Calculator</h1>

  <p><textarea id='input-matrix'>Enter Your 3x3 Matrix</textarea></p>

  <button onclick="run_invert()">Calculate</button>

  <div id="result-matrix"></div>
  
  <script>
    var default_matrix = 
            [[3,8,6],
            [4,3,6],
            [7,8,9]];

    function matrix_to_str(matrix) {
        return matrix.map(row => row.join(" ") ).join("\n");
    }

    var my_input = document.getElementById("input-matrix");
    my_input.value = matrix_to_str(default_matrix );

    function display_results(matrix) {
        document.getElementById("result-matrix").innerText = matrix_to_str(matrix);
    }

    function str_to_matrix(str) {
        return str.split("\n").map(row_str => row_str.split(" ").map(item => Number(item)));
    }


    function invert_matrix(M) { 

        if(M[0].length !== M.length) { 
            return;
        }

        var D = M[0][0] * (M[1][1] * M[2][2] - M[1][2] * M[2][1]) - M[0][1] * (M[1][0] * M[2][2] - M[1][2] * M[2][0]) + M[0][2] * (M[1][0] * M[2][1] - M[1][1] * M[2][0]); 

        var det = 1 / D; 

        var I = []; 

        for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++) { 
            I[I.length] = []
        }

        I[0][0] = [M[1][1] * M[2][2] - M[2][1] * M[1][2]] * det; 
        I[0][1] = [M[0][2] * M[2][1] - M[0][1] * M[2][2]] * det; 
        I[0][2] = [M[0][1] * M[1][2] - M[0][2] * M[1][1]] * det;
        I[1][0] = [M[1][2] * M[2][0] - M[1][0] * M[2][2]] * det;
        I[1][1] = [M[0][0] * M[2][2] - M[0][2] * M[2][0]] * det;
        I[1][2] = [M[1][0] * M[0][2] - M[0][0] * M[1][2]] * det;
        I[2][0] = [M[1][0] * M[2][1] - M[2][0] * M[1][1]] * det;
        I[2][1] = [M[2][0] * M[0][1] - M[0][0] * M[2][1]] * det;
        I[2][2] = [M[0][0] * M[1][1] - M[1][0] * M[0][1]] * det;

        return I;

    }


    function run_invert(){
        var current_matrix = str_to_matrix(document.getElementById("input-matrix").value);
        var inverted = invert_matrix(current_matrix);
        display_results(inverted);
    }



</script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

## What's left to you:

I ran the code, and something's clearly off with your matrix inversion calculation, or I misunderstood your code, etc. I've helped with your three asks, and it's up to you to get the numbers right. That's a whole 'nother world, math & js, and it's not covered here. But I expect some questions about rounding are in your future. Hope this helped.